# Convert system.currentTimeMillis() to MM-dd-yyyy HH:mm:ss.SSS in salesforce

Tags: apex, time

I want the following to happen in salesforce.

system.currentTimeMillis() to MM-dd-yyyy HH:mm:ss.SSS in salesforce.

Anyone could please explain me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try:

```
DateTime dt = DateTime.newInstance(system.currentTimeMillis());
system.debug(dt.format('yyyy-MM-dd\'T\'hh:mm:ss\'z\'));
```

Ofcourse, you can change the options under datetime format method to the way you like.